# Is this character based on a real person?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, law, racism, biography

In the 2014 historical novel *Natchez Burning*, by [Greg Iles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Iles), chapter 29:

> A black Mississippian who left his native state in the early 1950s to go to law school, Quentin Avery fought on the front lines of the civil rights movement, wherever those lines happened to be.

And in chapter 38:

> During the 1960s and '70s, Quentin argued four cases before the United States Supreme Court—one a landmark civil rights case—and won them all. He became a hero to many, and his name was mentioned in the same sentences as Thurgood Marshall and James Nabrit. But by the mid-1980s, the young firebrand had turned his mind to lucre rather than to justice, taking on high-profile (and very profitable) drug cases. In the 1990s he moved on to personal injury cases, two of which made him genuinely wealthy.

Is this fictional description modeled after someone real? If so, whom?

Comment: If the downvoter, or anyone else, could suggest an improvement to the question, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: This question boils down to: Were blacks involved in Civil Rights and did they plead cases in the Supreme Court?.  Odds are the answer is yes.

Comment: @Oldcat specifically a southern black man who went to law school in the north (or out of state, anyway) pre-[Little Rock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Rock_Nine).

Comment: Try looking up Thurgood Marshall, except he's older and did it earlier.

Comment: I don't think that this is a question about history, but I think it is possible that historical sources & methods could help answer the question.  I'm inclined to give the question the benefit of the doubt and leave it open.

Comment: I don't see the need for this particular question in history. If you want to know if Iles modeled the character after someone real send the author an e-mail. If you have a question is about blacks in Civil Rights and the Supreme Court than it's an historical question as Oldcat pointed and should be reformulated that way.